# Changing an Activity's TextView in a BroadcastReceiver (Android)

Tags: android, android-activity, textview, broadcastreceiver

I have a simple Android app with a single Activity that contains a TextView. I created a BroadcastReceiver whose purpose is to perform some numerical calculations, convert the result into a String, and then change the TextView's text value to that String. However, since the BroadcastReceiver is usually called when the App's Activity doesn't exist, I can't seem to find a way to access the Activity's TextView (I always get a NullPointerException).

I've read other articles here on StackOverflow that suggest implementing a Listener for my BroadcastReceiver with a callback method, but I'm honestly not sure how to implement this. I'm somewhat familiar with the concept of a callback method, I'm just not sure how to implement it in this context. Can anyone please suggest how I might accomplish this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Using an `AsyncTask` would do to perform operations in background. [Example one](http://www.javasrilankansupport.com/2012/11/asynctask-android-example-asynctask-in.html) [Example two](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.de/p/android-asynctask-example.html)

Note that you have to pass your `TextView` to the `AsyncTask` inside its constructor

Comment: I was thinking of doing that, but the problem is that as soon as the BroadcastReceiver fires, it will interrupt whatever the user is doing to bring the Activity to the forefront. I'd like the text change to occur in the background if possible.

Comment: could you elaborate? Your Activity starts after the calculation is performed? So why can't you put the result into an Intent?

Comment: Let me elaborate a bit - the TextView's String represents a Double, say 4.25. When the Activity first runs, the Manifest registers the BroadcastReceiver to fire every day at 12 AM. When the BroadcastReceiver fires, I'd like it to simply do the calculations and change the TextView. If I did what you suggested, when the BroadcastReceiver fires, it will bring the main Activity to the forefront. I want the calculations and TextView modifications to happen in the background so the user doesn't even need to be aware it's happening.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, using an Intent will start the main Activity, which will bring it to the front and interrupt whatever the user was doing.

Comment: why don't you use an AsyncTask if you need some operation to be done in the background?

Comment: Ooh...this might be what I'm looking for. I'm going to research it a bit, starting with the guide at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html . Thank you!

Comment: I updated my answer with some links which might help you. Good luck

Comment: Great find Maver1ck! One other question. Will I need to use a BroadcastReceiver to time the event to fire at midnight, or is there another (read: better) way to accomplish this (like using a service)? If I need to use a BroadcastReceiver, how can I make the call to the private .execute() method?

Comment: here's an example of using the AlarmService http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/07/30/how-to-use-alarm-service-in-android/   You call execute() by simply instantiating you AsyncTask Class like MyTask task = new MyTask (context, tvText); task.execute();

Comment: Thanks so much Maver1ck, you've been a huge help :)

Comment: Alright, so I had another thought on how to tackle this. I can access my app's SharedPreferences by calling context.getSharedPreferences() in the BroadcastReceiver, so I used this method to save a boolean value, "UpdateValue", and set it "true". Back in my activity's onResume() method, I have it check to see if this value is true, and if it is, then perform the necessary calculation and set the boolean back to false. I'm currently testing this, I'll let you know if it works.